# ::: Mod Re-Write /SubDir/ Content --> SubDomain Content

Tags: mod-rewrite

is this possible with Mod Re-Write?

1. IF either mobile users OR searchbots enter **server1.com/mobile/**
2. **server1/mobile/**  url **DOES NOT** change and
3. the content is served from **foo.server1.com**

Comment: Does it have to be mod_rewrite? Can you use mod_proxy instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^(iPhone.*|GoogleBot.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://foo.server1.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Note that with this approach you'd have to list every user-agent you want to match. You could have it all in one rule as I've done, or you could have a separate line for each one.